# How to make 3 elements overlap each other with CSS

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have 3 elements:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="foobar"></div>
```

I want `.foo` to overlap `.bar`, `.bar` to overlap `.foobar`, `.foobar` to overlap `.foo`.

Like this:

[image]

Is it possible with CSS?

Comment: Unless you count giving each element a `fixed` position with different `z-index` values that will achieve nothing, I've done nothing. Where do I start?

Comment: you are talking about varying z-indexes within the same image. for example foo will have a z-index of 2 on a corner and -2 or the opposite corner...interesting

Comment: @Jared - I am trying to conceptualize the requirement. the prblem I am getting stuck on is that the 3 images share the same plane. If we are working with transparent images we can get away with css 3d transforms and some css positioning

Comment: In a simple fasion, I'll say no as `z-index` works as a stack. However by using differnt `position` values you might get there, but it would be tricky. I would love to see a solution!

Answer (score 6):

There is no *normal* solution to this problem, however you can do some tricks to make the illusion.
If you create a `fake-foobar` inside of `.bar` like this markup, you can then position `.fake-foobar` inside `.bar` so that it looks like the corner of `.foobar`.

```
<div class="box foo"></div>
<div class="box bar">
    <div class="box fake-foobar"></div>
</div>
<div class="box foobar"></div>
```

Here is an image showing you the trick:
[image: Impossible Z-index]

[Demo with borders](http://jsfiddle.net/hLt5rguq/2/)
[Demo without borders](http://jsfiddle.net/hLt5rguq/)