# Cant find a way to do this

Tags: html, css

Hello Stack Overflow community.

I've got two div blocks. Which are images with width 1280px and 700px height.

In first block there is div with 100% height and 400px width floating left.

And in the second block there same size div but floating right. Problem is that the first block picture is png and her bottom is transparent about 10%.

Second block picture top is transparent 10%. I margin-top second picture to join them. And now i can't hide these divs with height 100% under them. I've tried using z-index but it hides only one.

So here is the jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/c7m6pm4w/ in this jsfiddle you can see that green and aqua is under blue. So how can I make that div.three(aqua) would be on div.four(blue) but under div.one(red). And div.two(green) would be on div.one(red), but under div.four(blue)?

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
<div class="four">
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the example of how it look like:
[image]

Comment: Post a demo mock up of what your result needs to be.

Comment: "So how can I make that div.three(aqua) would be on div.four(blue) but under div.one(red). And div.two(green) would be on div.one(red), but under div.four(blue)?". So confusing...It would be better if you wrote something like "three four one two" from bottom to top.

Comment: Please choose a better question title...

Comment: @ManojKumar Check my question i've updated with example

Comment: This layout can be achieved using some positioning changes. You want me to implement that?

Comment: @ManojKumar If you can please! :)

Answer (score 4):

I had to make some labeled paper stickers in order to understand what you mean (*the image in an original question has been added later*). As far as I have understood, you want something like this:

[image]

No, you cannot do this using CSS. At least, using z-indexes.

```
zi4 < zi3 < zi1
zi1 < zi2 < zi4

zi4 < zi1
zi1 < zi4

Impossible.
```

You can create an illusion of four items overlapping each other using the fifth div colored as the first one. However, there is really no normal reason of creating such an inconsistent, unsupportable HTML; that's why there is no normal solution.

Here is the [good related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644163/how-to-make-3-elements-overlap-each-other-with-css) with an example of "illusion".
Also, I have implemented a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxuah9qd/) for your case.

Comment: If this is the right answer, kudos to you. I can't understand the question properly at all.

Comment: @ManojKumar I hope it is. However, I just noticed that the OP has used `z-index` in his example. It looks like he wants something more complex :)

Comment: can you give a fiddle ?

Comment: I updated how i want it to look like, so we cant make it?

Comment: How can I make this whith these fake

Comment: @McLaren Create another one `div` which will fill the "gap" with another color creating an illusion of overlapping. By the way, what is the reason of making such a strange, unsupportable and inconsistent HTML block?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest aproach that comes to my mind is to split it all into a nine-cells grid:

HTML:

```
<div id="b11" class="cell"> </div>
<div id="b12" class="cell"> </div>
<div id="b13" class="cell"> </div>
<div id="b21" class="cell"> </div>
<div id="b22" class="cell"> </div>
<div id="b23" class="cell"> </div>
<div id="b31" class="cell"> </div>
<div id="b32" class="cell"> </div>
<div id="b23" class="cell"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.cell {
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
}
#b11 {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
#b12 {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
#b13 {
    background-color: red;
    xfloat: left;
}

#b21 {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
#b22 {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
}
#b23 {
    background-color: aqua;
    xfloat: left;
}

#b31 {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
#b32 {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
#b33 {
    background-color: aqua;
    xfloat: left;
}
```

(Of corse, you have to "tune" the individual widths and heights, and also add some extra cells for the borders.)

Why not?